# How to update Data in MongoDB when checked body is selected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend

How can I update data in MongoDB when I check the checkbox without submitting any form.

**My Schema**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    todos: [
        {
            task: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                required: 'Please Enter your Task',
            },
            dueDate: {
                type: Date,
                default: new Date(+new Date() + 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
            },
            dueTime: String,
            done: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false,
            },
        },
    ],
});
```

I want to update the `done` element which is in `todos` array.

I tried to do this.

Main Client Side JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.todo--checkbox').change(function () {
        let isChecked;
        if (this.checked) {
            isChecked = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/todo/' + this.value,
                type: 'PUT',
                data: { done: true },
            });
        } else {
            isChecked = false;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/todo/' + this.value,
                type: 'PUT',
                data: { done: false },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In the front-end I have set the value of the checkbox to the `_id` of the object.

**/routes/index.js** here I am handling my routes

```
router.put('/todo/:id', todoControllers.checkStatus);
```

And Finally I am handling that contorller in my **todoCOntroller.js**

```
exports.checkStatus = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.aggregate([
            { $unwind: '$todos' },
            { $match: { 'todos._id': req.params.id } },
        ]);

        // res.json(user);
        console.log(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    }
};
```

But I am not getting any `user` in my console.

Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: On which step do you have a trouble? Does `$unwind` return something?

Comment: Your whole `.change` function could be written `.change( function () { $.ajax({url:..., type:..., data: { done: this.checked })})`. Currently you are creating a new variable, which gets true or false depending if another variable is true or false, then you check whether it is true or false, and you duplicate your code, once with true, once with false. This whole overkill logic can be reduced to `data: { done: this.checked }`.

Comment: Yes ```$unwid``` is working fine and if I use ```const user = await User.aggregate([{ $unwind: '$todos' },{ $match: { 'todos.task': 'task4' } },]);``` It is also return the correct data. The problem is when I am using ```{ $match: { 'todos._id': req.params.id } },```

Comment: OK, I'm making a guess right now but maybe `todos.task._id: req.params.id`  Or if not, I am sure you will find the answer in the Docs.

Comment: ```todos.task._id: req.params.id``` didn't worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use aggregate. You can do it by using `$elemMatch`

```
const user = await User.find({
    todos: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.params.id } },
});
```

For more information read the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)